# Style Shape in Sketch from CSS

Tags: css, sketchapp

I have this CSS :

```
shadowColor: '#444',
shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },
shadowOpacity: 0.2,
shadowRadius: 8,
backgroundColor: 'white',
borderRadius: 10,
```

I'd like to replicate this style on Sketch.
But it uses 'Blur' and 'Spread' property for the shadow.
And i've noticed it uses box-shadow if you try to do it manually.

My question is :
I have this CSS styling. How could i apply it to my Shape.
(with or without plugin)

Sketch Version 47.1

Answer (score 0):

For me, the style that you have would be translated like this in sketch app :

```
shadowColor: '#444',                    // Color #444
shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },  // X & Y offset to 5px
shadowOpacity: 0.2,                     // Opacity 20 (the A in HSBA)
shadowRadius: 8,                        // Look like it's the Blur
backgroundColor: 'white',               // Bg color of the shape
borderRadius: 10,                       // Border radius of the shape
```

[image]

It is what you need ?

PS : This is not some CSS syntax that you have in your code.